# How to share custom filters in solr cluster setup?

Tags: solr

I have written a custom Solr filter and in a single node setup, I have placed the lib in ${solr_instance}/lib folder and it works fine.

I wanted to use the same custom filter in cluster environment.

I know that the config files are uploaded to zookeeper  and all the nodes download the config folder from zookeeper.

But how does the custom filters work? Will the jars get uploaded to zookeeper same like config files or I need to place the jars in each node.

If it gets uploaded to zookeeper, how should I do the configuration?

I am trying out in Solr 4.4.0 version and the clustering is managed by Cloudera manager 4.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment any external libraries will have to be distributed outside of zookeeper (and bundled with the application server), as they're necessary when instancing the server core (and loading Solr for the first time). The zookeeper integration is limited to distribution of configuration data at the time, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I got your point. But I am not sure about bundling the libraries with application server. Assuming I have only solr running in a distributed mode, where does this application server come into picture?

Comment: The application server would be Jetty in that case, as the Solr war runs through jetty. Part of your deploy process would be to deploy the libraries together with the server software. I'm not familiar with Cloudera, maybe they have something for that as well.